# D3js canvas and line are not visible

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js, svg

I have the following code which should to display drowned line in the canvas element.

```
var initCanvas = function () {

var episodeLengthInPixels = moment.duration(episodeLogLength).asSeconds() * episodeWidthMultiplication;
console.log("Length of chart is "+episodeLengthInPixels +" px");

try {
   canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", canvasHeight)
    .attr("class", canvasSelector);


//Draw the Line
  canvas.append("line")          // attach a line
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .attr("x1", 0)     // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", 500)
    .attr("y1", waveHeight)
    .attr("y2", waveHeight) ;

} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
}
```

Problem is that canvas and the line are available in the DOM model but are not visible (no exception is throwned). When i tried to work with SVG instead of the canvas, everything works fine.

How can I display the content in canvas using the D3.js library please? I tried to find any examples, but without the luck. Should i use D3.js fro canvas usage or something else (pure drawing to canvas in example)?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: canvas is not a DOM based thing. You get a canvas context and draw lines on it via the canvas API.

Answer (score 2):

`Canvas` and `SVG` are way different. It's not just a matter of changing "svg" for "canvas" in your `d3.select("body").append()` code. You should study the [canvas documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) and the [SVG documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG).

This, for instance, is how to draw a line in `canvas`:

```js
var chart = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 300);

var context = chart.node().getContext("2d");

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,100);//here you set the equiv. to X1 and Y1 in SVG
context.lineTo(400,100);//here you set the equiv. to X2 and Y2 in SVG
context.stroke();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Also, keep in mind that the fact that you see a given element when inspecting the DOM doesn't mean that the element will show up. You can make this very simple test using d3:

```
d3.select("body").append("div").append("charlesdarwin");
```

You're gonna see this inspecting the DOM:

```
<div>
    <charlesdarwin></charlesdarwin>
</div>
```

But, of course, you don't expect that this have any result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is kinda an example taken from here. 
https://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas

d3 and canvas are not the same.

```js
var base = d3.select("#foo");
var chart = base.append("canvas")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 300);

var context = chart.node().getContext("2d");
var data = [1,2,13,20,23];

var scale = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([10, 390])
  .domain([1,23]);

data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(scale(d), 150, 10, 10);
  context.fillStyle="red";
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
});
// Your line here... 
context.beginPath(); 
context.moveTo(10,10); 
context.lineTo(40,60); // x2,y2 ... 
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas">Examples here</a>

<div id="foo"></div>
```